# How can I add an auto increment field in a model based on total count of objects with same field value?

Tags: python, django, mariadb

I'm new to the whole Django thing and a bit lost. Sorry if the title is a bit confusing I'll try to clear things out.

So basically I have two models (**Folder and Document**). A **Document** can have a single **Folder** as one of its fields using a *Foreign Key*. Now I have another field in **Document** that needs to get the value of the **total Document objects** that share the same Folder and increase by one.

I've tried things I read on the docs (*aggregation, F() objects, overriding model's save() function*) as well as some answers is read here but didn't manage to get it right so I'm posting to get some help. Below is my models.py file with the two models and some comments for better understanding.

```
class Folder(models.Model):
    category = models.IntegerField()
    subCategory = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    desc = models.TextField()

class Document(models.Model):
    folder = models.ForeignKey(Folder, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField()

    #The field below needs to sum all Document objects that share 
    #the same folder value in the database + 1 and set it as its default value
    f_no = models.IntegerField(default=lambda: Document.objects.aggegate(Count('folder')) + 1)
```

Thank you in advance, any leads or clues are most welcome

**EDIT:**
Forgot to say that all management is done via Django's admin dashboard
if this has anything to do at all with my situation. I registered both
models in admin.py and that's all. I make new Folder objects when needed
and save Documents with one specific Folder in them each time

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a ManyToMany relation in the Folder, and add a created Document object into the Folder's ManyToMany relation.

**Models.py**

```py
class Folder(models.Model):
    category = models.IntegerField()
    subCategory = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    desc = models.TextField()
    documents = models.ManyToManyField('app.Document')
```

You can add can add documents to the folder by using `.add()` to the ManyToMany relation and the amount of documents in the relation by using `.count()`

ManyToMany relations are well documented here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but many to many means multiple documents share multiple folders and the opposite but what I need is many to one (Foreign Key) relationship because each Document has one and only one Folder where it belongs. On the other hand, each Folder can hold multiple documents and I'm trying to get the number of all those documents in each Folder.

Comment: The many to many relation means that many documents can share the same folder, not necessarily that documents have multiple folders, that depends on the way you implement it. This is the way I would do it, but you can also filter all document objects using the shared folder as a parameter and check the length of the query set.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a Document model object, it represents a single item. That single item shouldn't have a count of how many documents are in a file. The `f_no` you note should actually be in the Folder model.

Once you create a Document object that is related to a Folder object via ForeignKey, you can use signals to increment the `f_no` field that resides in the Folder object.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Document)
def increment_folder_item_count(sender, **kwargs):
    # get Folder object via Document model instance folder foreignkey field
    # folder.f_no += 1
    # folder.save()
```

Comment: My problem is that every document must have a unique number like a serial based on the folder it is assigned. For example if I have folder A with documents 1, 2 ,3 and folder B with documents 3, 5 the documents id are 1..5 but the f_no of each document is 1, 2 ,3 for folder A and 1, 2 for folder B. I hope this is a better explanation. Below is the code I copied and modified from you.

```@receiver(post_save, sender=Document)
def increment_folder_item_count(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    folder = instance.folder
    folder.f_no += 1
    folder.save()```

Comment: My only further recommendation would be 1. create an IntegerField in Folder and Document, 2. then use another signal function that overwrites the default Document save method which grabs the related Folder object's intField and adds another set of integers in addition to it. This way you can have document #A123 and #B123 depending on which folder you have..